# How to modify the filename of the S3 object uploaded using the Kafka Connect S3 Connector?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, s3-kafka-connector

I've been using the S3 connector for a couple of weeks now, and I want to change the way the connector names each file. I am using the HourlyBasedPartition, so the path to each file is already enough for me to find each file, and I want the filenames to be something generic for all the files, like just 'Data.json.gzip' (with the respective path from the partitioner).

For example, I want to go from this:

```
<prefix>/<topic>/<HourlyBasedPartition>/<topic>+<kafkaPartition>+<startOffset>.<format>
```

To this:

```
<prefix>/<topic>/<HourlyBasedPartition>/Data.<format>
```

The objective of this is to only make one call to S3 to download the files later, instead of having to look for the filename first and then download it.

Searching through the files from the folder called 'kafka-connect-s3', I found this file:
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/blob/master/kafka-connect-s3/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/s3/TopicPartitionWriter.java which at the end has some of the following functions:

```
private RecordWriter getWriter(SinkRecord record, String encodedPartition)
      throws ConnectException {
    if (writers.containsKey(encodedPartition)) {
      return writers.get(encodedPartition);
    }
    String commitFilename = getCommitFilename(encodedPartition);
    log.debug(
        "Creating new writer encodedPartition='{}' filename='{}'",
        encodedPartition,
        commitFilename
    );
    RecordWriter writer = writerProvider.getRecordWriter(connectorConfig, commitFilename);
    writers.put(encodedPartition, writer);
    return writer;
  }

  private String getCommitFilename(String encodedPartition) {
    String commitFile;
    if (commitFiles.containsKey(encodedPartition)) {
      commitFile = commitFiles.get(encodedPartition);
    } else {
      long startOffset = startOffsets.get(encodedPartition);
      String prefix = getDirectoryPrefix(encodedPartition);
      commitFile = fileKeyToCommit(prefix, startOffset);
      commitFiles.put(encodedPartition, commitFile);
    }
    return commitFile;
  }

  private String fileKey(String topicsPrefix, String keyPrefix, String name) {
    String suffix = keyPrefix + dirDelim + name;
    return StringUtils.isNotBlank(topicsPrefix)
           ? topicsPrefix + dirDelim + suffix
           : suffix;
  }

  private String fileKeyToCommit(String dirPrefix, long startOffset) {
    String name = tp.topic()
                      + fileDelim
                      + tp.partition()
                      + fileDelim
                      + String.format(zeroPadOffsetFormat, startOffset)
                      + extension;
    return fileKey(topicsDir, dirPrefix, name);
  }
```

I don't know if this can be customised to what I want to do but seems to be somehow near/related to my intentions. Hope it helps.

(Submitted an issue to Github as well: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/issues/369)

Comment: It's not possible to combine multiple topic partitions to write into one file. Otherwise, you can set the hourly rotation rate to just flush at the end of each hour, then you'd have one file topic-partition, per hour

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer maybe my post was unclear, but I'm already using that configuration and it's working fine. Every hour I get a new file for each topic I have, but what I want to modify is how the connector names these files. For example, I have a twitter topic and the connector is placing files in this path (respectively for each hour): topics/twitter/year=2020/month=10/day=07/hour=11/twitter+0+0002070632.json.gz. The actual filename is what I want to modify.

Comment: Well, you'd have to override the `fileKeyToCommit` method, but that's private and not exposed by any interface in the Partitioner, for example